# Find distinct Field list Spring data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-repositories

I have an entity TagLabel
it looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "tag_label")
    public class TagLabelDB implements Persistable<Long> {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long labelId;

    @Column(name = "study_instance_UID")
    private String stuInsUID;

    @Column(name = "tag")
    private String tag;

    ...
```

I would like to receive a list of distinct tag fields 
List tags        from JpaRepository

something like:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT t.tag FROM TagLabelDB t")
List<String> findDistinctTags();
```

The code above works fine,
but I wouldn't like to use @Query 
But Method name, Projection or Specification?...
It looks as a simple question, but I couldn't figure it out...

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), it should just be `findDistinctTag();` . Have you tried that?

Comment: It doesn't work, throws exception

Answer (score 0):

[`Distinct`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) keyword can occur in any place of the subject between `find` (and the other keywords) **and** `by`. It means that you **can't** use `distinct` like

```
List<String> findDistinctTagLabelDB();
```

Comment: It means that I would have to use a parameter? Shortly - impossible to make it that way?

Comment: For now, Spring Data JPA does not support distinct without `by`. Shortly, yes unfortunately it is.